# git keeps giving me error .git directory does not exist

Tags: git

I have searched all over google for a complete answer to this problem.

My hard drive failed so I bought a new drive and reinstalled Windows 10 with my cdkey in the side of my tower. Now, I have a got an github repo I've been working on for along time. I have tried `git init` then `git init add origin <url.git>` and both times I get the same problem. Infact just about every git commmand results in an error of the same missing .git directory.

Comment: Are you able to see the `.git` directory ? Its hidden by default. Try to view hidden items by checking `hidden items` in `view` of file explorer. Or just open a command prompt from inside your project's root directory and type `dir /a`. Or just type `ls .git` in your git bash from root location of project.  If you are able to see the `.git` directory then it is probably corrupted. One reason could be `HEAD` file is messed up or simply not there . It would be helpful if you could tell how your `.git` looks like if at all it is present.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided I do not know why you get the error you describe. However, you should only use `git init` if you are creating a brand new repo. If you want a repo on your local drive that already exists on GitHub.com you should use `git clone`.

Navigate to the directory you want to clone the repo in and use `git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY`

I always avoid doing data work from the `Documents` folder on Windows machines as OneDrive and other settings makes it so called "smart". `Documents` is great for Office files, but that is about it.

See documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository

Comment: ashbu@DESKTOP-8NAGQ06 MINGW64 ~/Documents
$ git clone https://github.com/ashburry-chat-irc/trio_ircproxy
Cloning into 'trio_ircproxy'...
C:/Users/ashbu/Documents/trio_ircproxy/.git: No such file or directory   <--- The same error again.

Comment: The `Documents` folder in Windows 10 is sometimes synced in OneDrive. This can create issues if OneDrive is busy with the file when your git client tries to access it. Can you try to create the folder `C:/Users/ashbu/github/` and try clone it there?

Comment: I disabled OneDrive when I installed Windows, but I will try anyway...

Comment: It worked when I cloned into c:/users/ashbu/gitub but still will not clone under ~\Documents

Comment: How do I mark a questions as answered?